# Query xml using extract over CLOB column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, xmltype

We are storing the xml in oracle database. The column type is CLOB.
I could fetch data from the xml tag with below query. When i execute the query i am getting null.

**XML in the column:**

```
<input xmlns="http://google.com/testsystem" 
       xmlns:testsystem="http://test.com/testSystem"          
       xmlns:tns="http://google.com/testService/">
      <ProcessData>      
        <reviewYear>2014-2015</reviewYear>
      </ProcessData>
    </input>
```

> Table name : test_table
>   Column name : input_xml
>   Column type : CLOB

**Query:**

```
select extract(xmltype(input_xml),'//reviewYear/text()').getStringVal() as data 
from test_table 
where id = 1;
```

**Result:**

```
DATA                  
------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify namespace, please, try next query

```
select extract(xmltype('<input xmlns="http://google.com/testsystem" 
       xmlns:testsystem="http://test.com/testSystem"          
       xmlns:tns="http://google.com/testService/">
      <ProcessData>      
        <reviewYear>2014-2015</reviewYear>
      </ProcessData>
    </input>'),'/input/ProcessData/reviewYear/text()', 'xmlns="http://google.com/testsystem" xmlns:testsystem="http://test.com/testSystem" xmlns:tns="http://google.com/testService/"').getStringVal() as data 
from dual
```

UPD.

for update try

```
select updatexml(xmltype('<input xmlns="http://google.com/testsystem" 
       xmlns:testsystem="http://test.com/testSystem"          
       xmlns:tns="http://google.com/testService/">
       <ProcessData>      
         <reviewYear>2014-2015</reviewYear>
       </ProcessData>
    </input>'), '/input/ProcessData/reviewYear/text()', '2013-2014', 
    'xmlns="http://google.com/testsystem" xmlns:testsystem="http://test.com/testSystem" xmlns:tns="http://google.com/testService/"').getclobval() as data 
from dual
```

Comment: How to update the tag if we have namespace? can you help with a sampl query? thanks in advance.

Comment: what tag do you want to change? tag or its value?

Comment: For example, i need to update <reviewYear>2014-2015</reviewYear> to <reviewYear>2013-2014</reviewYear>.